# Prove the regular 12-gon is constructible.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> Prove, both geometrically and then algebraically, that the regular 12-gon is contructible.

I'm pretty stuck on this one and trying to get my head around constructibility, so far I've seen that proving the 3-gon is contructible could be the first step.

What would be the easiest way to the geometric and the algebraic proofs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Doubling the number of sides on a regular polygon you've constructed is quite easy.

Comment: See a geometric construction at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon#Dodecagon_construction

Answer (score 2):

Algebraically, a regular $n$-gon is constructible if and only if $\cos (2\pi/n)$ is a constructible number.

$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{12})=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ is clearly constructible.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I know it may be completely trivial but could you explain the geometric proof?

Comment: @user12002 Geometric proof: start with an equilateral triangle, then find a way to double the sides.

Answer (score 0):

There is little more to it than just constructing a perpendicular bisector, really.

1. Start with a line segment $AB$.
2. Center the compasses on $A$ and construct the circle through $B$.
3. Center the compasses on $B$ and construct the circle through $A$.  Define $C, D$ as the points of I resection of the two circles now constructed.
4. Draw line segments $AC$ and $CD$ thus identifying a $\angle ACD$ which measures 30°.
5. Center the compasses on $C$ and draw a circle through $A$; this circle passes through $E$ on $CD$ so that $\angle ACE$ measures 30° and $\arc AE$ follows suit.
6. Draw chord $AE$ and copy this around the circle centered on $C$.

Comment: Aargh!  The software does not like my notation for an arc!  How to solve?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inscribe a regular hexagon ( we know this algebraically and geometrically) in a circle and next it is possible to construct angle bisectors of the 6 angles at circle center intersecting circumcircle at new 6 more vertices.